# How to escape single quote in java's SimpleDateFormat

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

I have a date input date like this:
{ts '2012-08-13 02:30:01'}

I believe I can escape the invalid part with single quotes, but I have a single quote within the invalid part. How do I escape that? I tried a couple of patterns but it is not working.

Thanks,

Comment: What you tried? Post relevant code.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

According to the [javadocs for SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

> Text can be quoted using single quotes (') to avoid interpretation. **`"''"` represents a single quote**.

So a format string like:

```
"'{ts '''yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'''}'"
```

should match `{ts '2012-08-13 02:30:01'}`

Comment: That's a little tricky, as it might appear like you've got 3 quotes there before yyyy. E.g. '''yyy. But its a couple of "literal" sections.
1: '{ts '
2: ''
3: ''
4: '}'

Answer (score 4):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDateTime.parse( 
    "{ts '2012-08-13 02:30:01'}"
    .replace( "{ts '" , "" )       // Delete prefix.
    .replace( "'}" , "" )          // Delete suffix.
    .replace( " " , "T" )          // Yields `2012-08-13T02:30:01`. In standard ISO 8601 format.
)                                  // Returns a `LocalDateTime` object.
```

## *java.time*

`SimpleDateFormat` is obsolete, supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

### `java.time.DateTimeFormatter`

Use `DateTimeFormatter` instead, to define formatting patterns for use in parsing/generating strings.

That class uses a pair of single quotes `''` as the escape value for a single quote. Otherwise, a single quote is used to mark text to be ignored by the formatter.

### Simple text manipulation to get ISO 8601 string

But no need for a custom formatting pattern in your case. Your inner text is nearly compliant with the ISO 8601 standard used by default in *java.time*. Just do some string manipulation of your input text.

```
String input = 
    "{ts '2012-08-13 02:30:01'}"
    .replace( "{ts '" , "" ) 
    .replace( "'}" , "" ) 
    .replace( " " , "T" )
;
```

Yields `2012-08-13T02:30:01`.

### Parse as `LocalDateTime`

Then parse as a `LocalDateTime` object.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( input ) ;
```

Answer (score 3):

This is what worked for me

```
SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM''yy", Locale.ENGLISH)

01 Jan'20
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried escaping the single quote by another single quote? Otherwise the better way might be to exctract the relevant part (between the quotes) using a regular expression, and only then applying the SimpleDateFormat.