# Why do i get Unparseable date exception ?

Tags: java, string, simpledateformat

```
    String DATE_FORMAT = "`";
    Object value = null;
    String date = "2014-02-02";

    try {
        value = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT).parse(date);
        System.out.println(value);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
```

as i saw in the java docs, this DATE_FORMAT will avoid interpretation, maybe i didn't understand it correctly.

so what am i doing wrong ?

Comment: Where in the documentation is this said?

Comment: yea i guess i didnt get it, what is this means:

Text can be quoted using single quotes (') to avoid interpretation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you refer to this:

> Date and time formats are specified by date and time pattern strings.
>   Within date and time pattern strings, unquoted letters from 'A' to 'Z'
>   and from 'a' to 'z' are interpreted as pattern letters representing
>   the components of a date or time string. Text can be quoted using
>   single quotes (') to avoid interpretation. "''" represents a single
>   quote. All other characters are not interpreted; they're simply copied
>   into the output string during formatting or matched against the input
>   string during parsing.

This means you can avoid interpretation of the text of the pattern adding a single quote to the parts you want to avoid.

For example if I get my String dates with a text I want not to be interpreted as part of the date I can do something like this:

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("'mydate' yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
try {
    df.parse("mydate 2014-04-01 12:30:00");
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This will not give any exception. On the other hand, this will:

```
  SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("'mydate' yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    try {
        df.parse("mydates 2014-04-01 12:30:00"); //check the additional s
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

In short I think you missinterpreted the specs.

More info: [How to escape single quote in java's SimpleDateFormat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11941807/how-to-escape-single-quote-in-javas-simpledateformat)

Comment: yea i understood where was my mistake,
thanks for the detailed explanation !

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
String DATE_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd";
Date value  = null;
String date = "2014-02-02";

try {
    value = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT).parse(date);
    System.out.println(value);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

And  [Read](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)